# Java - Changing JLabel Frontcolor in extern function

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

As a beginner in Java i try to create a Window Application "Game" with the help of windowsbuilder (eclipse plugin).
Now as i try to change The label in an extern function (allblack()) the console gives out the following errors when i press the specific button (The window gets displayed correctly):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Leiterspiel.allblack(Leiterspiel.java:81)
    at Leiterspiel$2.mouseClicked(Leiterspiel.java:234)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Leiterspiel.allblack(Leiterspiel.java:81)
    at Leiterspiel$2.mouseClicked(Leiterspiel.java:234)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'd be greatful if anyone could explain it to me as the same code as in  "allblack()" works in "inizialize()".
Thanks

```
[Pre-sampled import]
public void allblack()
 {
    l1.setForeground(Color.black);
    l2.setForeground(Color.black);
 }
 public void initialize() {

    frmDasLeiterspiel = new JFrame();
    frmDasLeiterspiel.setResizable(false);
    frmDasLeiterspiel.setTitle("Das Leiterspiel");
    frmDasLeiterspiel.setBounds(100, 100, 420, 420);
    frmDasLeiterspiel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmDasLeiterspiel.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("1");
    l1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    l1.setBounds(340, 190, 50, 50);
    l1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    frmDasLeiterspiel.getContentPane().add(l1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("2");
    l2.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    l2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    l2.setBounds(278, 190, 50, 50);
    frmDasLeiterspiel.getContentPane().add(l2);
    [....]
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Roll the dice!");
    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            allblack();
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(12, 294, 378, 25);
    frmDasLeiterspiel.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    [...]
    }
```

Comment: The labels you are creating are local to the `initialize` method . Replace `JLabel l1 = new JLabel("1");` with `l1 = new JLabel("1");` and `JLabel l2 = new JLabel("2");` with `l2 = new JLabel("2");` to initialize the actual  labels .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the variables l1 and l2 only exitst in the initialize method.
try this:

```
public void allblack() {
    l1.setForeground(Color.black);
    l2.setForeground(Color.black);
}

private JLabel l1,l2;
public void initialize() {

    frmDasLeiterspiel = new JFrame();
    frmDasLeiterspiel.setResizable(false);
    frmDasLeiterspiel.setTitle("Das Leiterspiel");
    frmDasLeiterspiel.setBounds(100, 100, 420, 420);
    frmDasLeiterspiel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmDasLeiterspiel.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    l1 = new JLabel("1");
    l1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    l1.setBounds(340, 190, 50, 50);
    l1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    frmDasLeiterspiel.getContentPane().add(l1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    l2 = new JLabel("2");
    l2.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    l2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    l2.setBounds(278, 190, 50, 50);
    frmDasLeiterspiel.getContentPane().add(l2);
    [....]
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Roll the dice!");
    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            allblack();
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(12, 294, 378, 25);
    frmDasLeiterspiel.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    [...]
    }
```